# Filtering Data on form to get multiple Query tables or forms in a Subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

[image: Getting the tables on left to the subform in parent form] I want to get different Query tables or Forms to Subform based on the query table name I enter in the text on the parent form.
Ex: If I select X, I should X Query data sheet on a subform
If I select Y I should data from Y table
I tried selecting the tables using the IF else option on VBA which failed.

Comment: You want to apply filter criteria? Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Instead of getting the data filtered by ID, name or date. I want to get diff table based on the radio button I select as in the picture attached above. Ex: When I click on Teachers By Gender option I want to get that query table and to get the other is selected.

Comment: Code can set the SourceObject property of subform/subreport container control. SourceObject can be a table/query/form/report.

Comment: Thanks June7 for SourceObject Property concept, I had managed to get the query tables appear dynamically based on the selection made in Parent form and get multiple types of tables in Subform.